# when i tried to add details into sql database,i got the error.this is my function to add

Tags: c#, sql

"There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement"

```
public bool AddStock(string BIKENAME,string ENGNUM,string CHASE,string COUNT,string ONR,string COLOR,string DATE)       
{
          try
          {

              SqlConnection con = SetSqlConnection();
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
              cmd.Connection = con;


              cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date)VALUES('"+ BIKENAME +"'),('"+ ENGNUM +"'),('"+ CHASE +"'),('"+ COUNT +"'),('"+ ONR +"'),('"+ COLOR +"'),('"+ DATE +"')";
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              return true;
          }
          catch (SqlException ex)
          {
              return false;

          }
}
```

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection attacks and then use a parameterised query

Comment: Obligatory link to wikipedia article on sql injection attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the [Bobby Tables Alert](http://xkcd.com/327/), your `insert` statement is malformed: you need to enclose *all* values in parenthesis, not each individual one:

```
insert into ... values (..., ..., ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date)VALUES('"+ BIKENAME +"'),('"+ ENGNUM +"'),('"+ CHASE +"'),('"+ COUNT +"'),('"+ ONR +"'),('"+ COLOR +"'),('"+ DATE +"')";
```

to:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date)VALUES('"+ BIKENAME +"','"+ ENGNUM +"','"+ CHASE +"','"+ COUNT +"','"+ ONR +"','"+ COLOR +"','"+ DATE +"')";
```

to make it work.

But - as per many other answers and comments here - it is better to use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for some reason, you still need to do insert statements this way (there are better alternatives like linq-to-sql), tying strings together like that is just bad. Sql injections, unreadable codes?
You should at least do something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date)VALUES(@BIKENAME, @ENGNUM, @CHASE, @COUNT, @ONR, @COLOR, @DATE)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BIKENAME", "real value here");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENGNUM", "real value here");
...
...

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(rowsAffected > 0) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the syntax of query is false try to use this one

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date) 
VALUES('"+ BIKENAME +"','"+ ENGNUM +"','"+ CHASE +"','"+ COUNT +"','"+ ONR +"','"+ COLOR +"','"+ DATE +"')";
```

also to avoid sql injection you should use a parameterized query like :

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock1 (bikename,engineno,chaseno,count,onr,color,date) 
VALUES(@BIKENAME ,@ENGNUM ,@CHASE,@COUNT,@ONR ,@COLOR ,@DATE)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BIKENAME", BIKENAME);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ENGNUM ", ENGNUM );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CHASE", CHASE);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COUNT", COUNT);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ONR", ONR );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COLOR", COLOR );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", DATE);
```